# How do I import a spreadsheet on an already imported spreadsheet?

Tags: import

We have a daily requirement to import a spreadsheet on an already imported spreadsheet within sharepoint. This is to assist with daily and consistent updates, it would take too much time to add them one by one

Your help is appreciated

Comment: You want to append data to an existing spreadsheet?

Comment: "already imported spreadsheet within sharepoint" do you mean an Excel file that's sitting in SharePoint? Or you imported an Excel file into a list and you want to update the list?

Answer (score 1):

Use [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) for that.
Here is a Blog Post how to get it to Work with Sharepoint

http://devmoss.wordpress.com/2011/02/23/sp-excel-docs-the-easy-way/

Comment: We  require relevant answers and disclosure of any affiliation with  products or websites (i.e. your blog). Please see [May I promote products or websites I  am affiliated with here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) for guidelines.